# Empty response after updating to Node v8

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I had a perfectly fine working Node application (MEAN.js based originally, so working with Mongodb and Express).

After updating from Node v4.4 to Node v8.11, and doing an 'npm install', I first ran into some errors which I was able to solve (or silence) by upgrading packages mongoose (from 3.8.x to 4.4.x) and connect-mongo (from 0.4.x to 2.0.x) and the mongodb (node-package) to 3.x.x.

What happens now when I start the application (with 'node server.js') is that I get a message that 'ok, https server is running on port 444' (like normally), but when I go to https://localhost:444 (like I normally do) I get an ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE and nothing shows up in the Console or Sources or anything.

Does anyone know a suggestion or at least direction to start lookin in? I changed nothing in the code, only the abovementioned upgrades.

PS: I must admit I don't actually have an urgent reason to update to Node v8, other than 'thinking it's good to stay up-to-date'.

Comment: As you mention, you also updated many packages, you must check breaking changes of that packages

Comment: Can you share your service and server code